# Continuity and close map . [Metric Space.]

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The question is - Show that the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=x$ is continuos but it is not closed ..I don't know how to prove this, I am approaching in this way, I am analyzing this question and found that this function is onto but not one one. i have to show that it is not a closed map , i.e it does not send closed sets onto some closed sets but i take some examples like a unit circle then f(unit circle) comes out to be [-1,1] which is closed in R , i take many other examples as well but cannot be able to contradict this ,, also how to claim it is continuos map , iam proceeding like this  let i need to check continuity at the point (1,2)- let epsilon > 0 is fixed now consider d(f(x,y)-f(1,2)) =d(x,1)=mod(x-1) , so i need to find a delta>0 such that if (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2 < delta  then mod(x-1)<=mod(1+ delta-1)=delta

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE.  Thank you for including the work you've done so far and your sticking points.  Can you please format your question to make it readable?  It will attract more answers that way.

Comment: I have just started reformatting your question into LaTeX/MathJax. I hope that now you can finish it.

Comment: thank you but iam new , i don't know how to use LaTex/MathJax .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Consider $g(x)=1/x$ and projection of its graph.

Comment: Thank you , i get it , so u are taking A ={(x,1/x) : x belongs to R-{0} } then it is closed i get it through diagram but how to do a mathematical proof  , and f(A)=R-{0} which is not closed , Am i right , is this what you want to say ?  :) .

Comment: Yes. And an easy way to show that every branch of $1/x$ is closed is to observe that it is homeomophic to $\mathbb{R}$.